# Refraction bending with planar surfaces in Cycles (2.78b)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials

I was always under the impression that straight lines should refract and reflect via planar surfaces into straight lines.  Cycles seems not to do this in certain instances.  In the video below you can see it best on the left face at the start and the right face at the end of the sequence. At first I thought it was a problem with my HDRi but it seems surrounding geometry creates the same effect.  Am I wrong in my assumptions, do I have some settings or parameters incorrect in my materials or environment or is this a "feature" of Cycles?

[[image: Video thumbnail]

Refraction example on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z05HqjDIfSU)

Here's the Blend file (slightly edited since this video was made):

[image]

Here's a single face of the cube and no HDRi showing the effect.

[image: Single Plane]

Comment: It's a light feature! When rendering with the default perspective camera, you are correcting the 'perspective projection distortion', which is what happens in real cameras (tipical panoramic distortion). When you put a refractive object in it, you are forcing the distortion to take place in the object location (the object becomes a new focal point!). What looks strange is not the refraction, but the absence of distortion when using a small focal length and the default perspective camera.

Comment: This render result is indeed physically incorrect. Can you share your scene and setup? I wasn't able to replicate this with a 35mm camera, a 1.3 IOR glass shader and HDRi. Note that refraction phenomena on HDRi are limited - here is an example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/egRBd.png

Comment: @Jerryno I've edited the question to include the .blend file.  I've removed the HDRi and the effect is still visible.

Comment: I think it is correct. For the refraction in the front plane the light is passing through two parallel planes and so ends up at the same angle as originally incident. As the HDR background is effectively out at infinity the parallel rays appear to be unaffected by the refraction. For the distorted "refraction" in the side, it's entering the side, *reflecting* off the back surface and passing out the opposite side. This means that the rays travel a different distance through the cube depending on where on the side face they hit, producing the 'bend'.

Comment: @RichSedman yep, the HDRi does not shift because it's in infinity. Including a close up object (like that window) in HDRi makes the render physically incorrect (that's what I meant with incorrect:). But I am fairly sure if the cube is homogenous inside and the sides are planar you cannot get any kind of bulging distortion.

Comment: I've added another image. In this I've removed the HDRi as I think we are getting distracted by that. The cage around the glass cube is geometry in the scene made from a subdivided cube with a wireframe modifier applied.  I've also removed five faces of the glass cube, which I realise creates an artificial situation, and it still shows the issue.  I've done a lot more testing today and feel that there might just be a bug in the way that the refracted ray is interpolated across the interior of the face.  It doesn't look like it is a problem with the normal as a fully glossy shader looks fine.

Comment: @PaulMc Yes I came to the same conclusion as you. Tested your .blend thoroughly and it looks like a Cycles bug indeed. Not a normal issue I can confirm. Before posting this I just wanted to compare with other renderers when I get home. If this indeed proves to be a bug it will be a big one..

Comment: @PaulMc So it is like this also in LuxRender.

Comment: @Jerryno I do think this is correct. I think the distortion is more pronounced the more the viewpoint approaches the plane - so it would be perfectly straight if the viewpoint was effectively at infinity but gets more pronounced the closer you get to the plane. Think of the view from the bottom of a swimming pool looking up. Reverse the refraction (ie, air to water rather than water to air) and the distortion would curve the other way.

Comment: @RichSedman There should be no distortion. You see the things behind the boundary as if looking from another location and with different field of view (zoom). A straight line should remain straight line, no distortion possible. This diagram I made should clear that up: http://i.imgur.com/mNUUWqM.png. It's the same with the underwater example: http://img.tfd.com/ElMill/thumb/F0R-07-S2958.jpg. The refraction keeps the lines undistorted: https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/images/ic/640xn/p023hqnk.jpg. Distortion should only happen if the surface is not planar or volume not homogeneous.

Comment: @Jerryno I disagree - while the rays are obviously straight, the resulting image viewed through the planar surface is not. Consider this image https://goo.gl/images/XtAlqF  - the edges of the sky is distorted in towards the centre - directly above is not affected while the greater the angle to the normal of the surface, the more it is distorted in towards the centre. Non-radial straight lines would become bent around the centre point.

Comment: Here's another image to demonstrate https://goo.gl/images/JLuXkI - assuming that the pool side and fence are straight. The fence posts show the distortion quite well - with the one at the far top-right most obviously affected (assuming it's not due to the ripples).

Comment: Well I'm about to concede that I'm wrong.  Tests with POVRay and Blender Internal both show the same effect and if Cycles and LuxRender do as well then perhaps the maths is correct.  I'm guessing that the flaw in my logic is that we are not used to seeing planar surfaces with materials that have an IOR as low as 1.3.  Bumping up the IOR to 1.5 seems to straighten out all the distortion. @JerryNo thanks for the support but I think that for IOR values between 1 and 1.5 this distortion is normal.

Comment: @RichSedman, thanks for the examples, they do support this idea.

Comment: @RichSedman so I tested couple more renderers and the same results. I did the math and draw the rays in Autocad and the projected refracted rays do not intersect in single point! I used the shnells formula n1/n2=sin(alpha)/sin(beta). All diagrams on web like this one: http://img.tfd.com/ElMill/thumb/F0R-07-S2958.jpg and others are lies. Also what they teach in schools is very simplified.. So the closer the camera is the bigger the distortion. IOR of 1.3 should be fine, water is 1.33.  The distortion is always there for anyIOR, but if camera is further away it disappears fast. You were right!

Comment: @jerryno - thanks! I think the school point of view is typically that the incoming rays assumed to be parallel from infinity so I guess that normally avoids the problem. Impressed that you've managed to do the math - it was making my head hurt ;-) Do you feel able to put together an answer for this - I think you're probably better qualified for it and could probably do it a whole lot more justice (for the maths) than I could.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On first look it might seem that *[refraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refraction)* on planar surfaces will not distort the image, but just linearly bent it or zoom it:

[image]

In real world there are very few examples where the distortion is clearly visible, one of them being *refraction* on water level:

[image]

*(Thanks to @RichSedman for pointing this out and patiently making me dig deeper to find the truth and how it works.)*

Refraction follows the [Snell's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snell's_law). This means that for every [IOR value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refractive_index) there exist a *critical angle* after which the ray won't be *refracted* but *reflected*:

[image]

We can see this in the above pictures, where the *refraction* is surrounded by the *reflection* of pool or sea bed. We will return to this (in Cycles) later. What we also see is the distortion of those *refracted* rays, so lets tackle the distortion first:

It's best to start with *reflection* analogy. Reflection is much simpler - the angle of incidence is the same as angle of reflection - their relationship is *linear* (unlike with refraction). By tracing the reflected rays, we can construct a single(!) virtual viewing point B, from which we see the reflected image:

[image]

Doing this with refracted rays (and drawing them in CAD with Snell's formula) reveals, that the rays do not intersect into a single virtual viewing point, but into infinitely many of them (because the relationship between incidence angle and refracted angle is not linear). This means that every piece of the refraction we see from different perspective and that is the reason for the distortion (every 2 rays create a virtual viewing point in different location):

[image]

Now let's see how this behaves in Cycles - left how it changes with distance to camera (single refractive quad with IOR 1.3) and right how it changes with IOR (1.0 to 2.0):

[image]

This is physically correct behavior. By knowing this you are now able to create a panoramic fish-eye lens camera from simple perspective camera and a refractive quad (if the engine can do refractions but has no such camera option:)

But what Cycles doesn't do on it's own is to change the ray from refractive to reflective after the critical angle just with the Refractive shader (naturally) - it is just black. For this there is the Fresnel node that after the critical angle gives 1.0 mixing factor to mix in Glossy shader:

[image]

The glass shader has all this already build in.