# Panoramic camera in Eevee engine

Tags: camera, panoramic, eevee-render-engine

Does anyone know if the Panoramic/equertangular/360º camera will work with the Eevee engine? Maybe realtime viewport and/or when we press the render button?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Hi! Yes, the panoramic camera menu don't have any option to 360º render. And when I press to render, it make a normal camera image.

Comment: Please check this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/75254/7777 answer on how to make panoramic distortion with a refractive plane. It won't be 360°, but with multiple renders you can stitch it together. You can also make 6 normal renders of 90° squares to form a cube map and then convert it into 360°panorama.

Answer (score 3):

EEVEE doesn't support Panoramic, for now.

:(

Comment: I have no idea why this was downvoted twice. "No" or "This is not possible" is a perfectly valid answer for a question asking if something is possible/will work.